# Detect each polygons in an image

Tags: image-processing

Considering this image:

[image]

Is there a way to colorize each tiles independently? My problem is that

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPg28.jpg"];
Colorize@img
```

gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

where polygons with very light colours are merged.

Note that `EdgeDetect[img, 1, .05]` produces:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

if it can help.

---

**Ideally**, the idea would be to colour the tiles independently (`Colorize` colours them in terms of their "blackness"). That would imply that one detects the polygons and recreate them, which is harder than "only" colouring them in terms of their pre-existing colours.

Please note I have absolutely no knowledge in [image-processing](/questions/tagged/image-processing).

Comment: In case you don't realize the fuzziness at the edges is an artifact of jpeg compression. If you have the original to work with you'll have an easier time of it.

Comment: @george2079 I don't have the original work for the real case. I guess that I could try to vectorize it with InkScape though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [requested](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55248/how-can-i-extract-the-outline-of-bubbles-in-my-image#comment158937_55285):

```
i = Import["http://i.imgur.com/Y87duSz.jpg"]
n = TotalVariationFilter[i, 0.02]
e = EdgeDetect[n, 1, 0.02]
(d = DistanceTransform[ColorNegate[e], Padding -> 0]) // ImageAdjust
m = MaxDetect[d, 2]
(w = WatershedComponents[ColorNegate[d], m]) // Colorize
```

[image]

Kind of ugly with the rough edges, but there you go.

Answer (score 4):

This is too long for a comment.

The difficulty with the example image is that it is not "clean" in the sense that it contains pixel gradients. There are 256 colors present despite the fact that there are only 50 triangles. This is why you get the imperfect output from `EdgeDetect`, and it is going to make any image processing more difficult.

We can see this problem if we try a naïve conversion with `ColorRules`:

```
img = Import["http://i.imgur.com/Y87duSz.jpg"];
colors = DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[ImageData[img], 1]];
newColors = ColorData["AvocadoColors"] /@ Rescale[Range[Length@colors]];
Colorize[img, ColorRules -> MapThread[Rule, {colors, newColors}]]
```

[image]

In this case, sorting the source colors (because the replacement colors are sequential) makes this less obvious:

```
colors2 = Sort@DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[ImageData[img], 1]];
Colorize[img, ColorRules -> MapThread[Rule, {colors2, newColors}]]
```

[image]

You can use `ColorRules` to control how shapes get colored, but that will require some manual input or some other logic based on the particular image. The rules can involve patterns.

By way of comparison, look at this "clean" image:

```
Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}], 1];
MeshPrimitives[DelaunayMesh[%], 2];
Riffle[%, ColorData["AvocadoColors"] /@ Rescale[Range@Length@%]] // Graphics;
Image[%]
```

[image]

```
EdgeDetect[%, 1, .05]
```

[image]

```
Colorize[%%]
```

[image]

Comment: "Too long for a comment" you sure? :P

Comment: When I saw the last image I thought you came up with it based on my image, but you produced a "clean" one :P You tricked me! :D

Comment: @Öskå Beware, Mathematica SE can be an emotional roller coaster :P

Comment: Unfortunately `ColorRules` is an option for `Colorize` since _v9_ apparently :)

Comment: Bah. I only started using MMA in v9 so I have no idea what didn't exist before then :( You could implement the same strategy with a custom `ColorFunction` though.

Comment: This is beautiful!

Answer (score 3):

*Update:*

Here's what I came up with trying to color every triangle independently regardless of its brightness.

Create a marker for [`ImageForestingComponents`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageForestingComponents.html):

```
dim = 5;(* number of rectangles *)
marker = 
 Rasterize[
  Graphics[{White, 
    Point /@ 
     Table[Sequence @@ {{x, y + .05}, {x, y - .05}}, {x, .5/dim, 
       1 - .5/(dim), 1/dim}, {y, .5/dim, 1 - .5/dim, 1/dim}]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, Background -> Black], 
  ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[img]]
```

Colorize independently:

```
Colorize[ImageForestingComponents[img, marker, 1]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

For different arrangement of triangles you will have to generate a different marker image.

---

*Original answer:*

You can choose a different `ColorFunction`:

```
img = Import["http://i.imgur.com/Y87duSz.jpg"];
Colorize[img, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That fixes the merged white tiles indeed, sadly it doesn't provide a way to colour the tiles independently.. :) And that would be uber cool.

Comment: @Öskå What do you mean color them independently? You can specify exact color conversions using a custom `ColorFunction` or `ColorRules`.

Comment: @shrx It's interesting that `"DarkRainbow"` (default scheme) doesn't work. Even when I made the conversions manually it still reduced the image from 256 colors to 213.

Comment: @mfvonh Right, they are indeed independently coloured here.., ideally I would love to be able to colour the middle tiles for example in black, and the rest in white. Thus it becomes a "I would need to lists of polygons" out of the image., which is harder.

Comment: @Öskå Are you looking for a generic solution? In these cases it is helpful if we can assume some properties about the image (so we're not relying on things like `EdgeDetect`, which as you see isn't always that great)

Comment: @mfvonh Once again, _ideally_ it would need to be generic indeed. This is only a test image :)

Comment: @Öskå see my update

Comment: @shrx I need to go now for a few mins, I will comment on this later :)

Comment: I unfortunately get [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vAE5y.png). Without the weird area it's much better than before indeed.

Comment: Strange, what version are you using? I'm using V10 on OS X 10.9.4.

Comment: @shrx I'm on v8 Linux :)

Comment: Hmm, the documentation does mention `ImageForestingComponents` was updated in v10 but the only change seems to be the added support for 3D images. Maybe you can check if you get different results with the examples in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageForestingComponents.html).