# How can I extract the outline of bubbles in my image?

Tags: image-processing, image

I have an image:

[image]

I tried to extract the outline of the bubbles, but I met with some problems. Firstly I tried the method used in *Mathematica* documentation for [`Analyze Segmented Cells In An Image`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/AnalyzeSegmentedCellsInAnImage.html), but it didn't work well, I got an irregular figure:

[image]

Then I tried the function `EdgeDetect`. Things got a little bit better, but it's still not what I want. Could you please help me with my problem?

Comment: One question is.., what do you want out of it? The number of bubbles?

Comment: I want the outline of each bubble.

Comment: I've got something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Q50RT.jpg) not perfect, but better :)

Comment: @Öskå I think it's much better than my picture! Could you please share your method with us?

Comment: Rahul's answer is even better ;o) Quite the same method though :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNXEV.jpg"];
n = TotalVariationFilter[image, 0.05]
b = LocalAdaptiveBinarize[n, 50]
s = DeleteSmallComponents[ColorNegate[DeleteSmallComponents[b, 20^2]], 20^2]
(d = DistanceTransform[s]) // ImageAdjust
m = MaxDetect[d, 10]
(w = WatershedComponents[ColorNegate[d], m]) // Colorize
c = ComponentMeasurements[w, {"Centroid", "EquivalentDiskRadius"}, #2 < 50 &];
Show[image, Graphics[{Thick, Red, Circle @@@ c[[All, 2]]}], ImageSize -> 1280]
```

[image]

<sup>(Click for bigger.)</sup>

Run the code to see the intermediate steps.

[Thanks to nikie](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/33495/484) for the second half of this answer.

`LocalAdaptiveBinarize` is new in version 10, but all it does is "creates a binary image by replacing values above the mean of the range-$r$ neighborhood with $1$ and others with $0$." So you can replace it with something like, say,

```
b = Binarize[ImageSubtract[n, MeanFilter[n, 50]], 0]
```

which gives similar results, though not identical for some reason. Possibly there's a more elegant way to do it.

Comment: Do you think that the same method could work with `Polygon`s? I asked [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55127/detect-each-polygons-in-an-image) question hoping to get the same kind of answer :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think
    `// ImageAdjust`
    `// Colorize` 
are of no use during the processing, since `d` and `w` aren't changed by these 2 commands. So you just put them here to show the effect of `ImageAdjust` and `Colorize`? 
What's more, **for users using _Mathematica_ below 10**:
Note that function `LocalAdaptiveBinarize` appears only in _Mathematica_ 10, which means that maybe you cannot use `LocalAdaptiveBinarize`. For concrete solution, Rahul has showed above.

Comment: I put the `// ImageAdjust` and `// Colorize` there to visualize what the intermediate steps are doing, because you can't tell anything from looking at `d` and `w` directly. I've updated my answer with a replacement for `LocalAdaptiveBinarize`.